# FirstName, LastName and Email are null in graph.facebook.com API call results

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve userdata from facebook using java and facebook4j facebook api wrapper.

Here is the class used to retrieve user after receiving code from facebook:

```
public static User getFacebookUser(final String code) {
    String access_token = "";

    String authURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
            "client_id=" + APP_ID + "&" +
            "redirect_uri=" + "http://localhost:8080/online-screen/login" + "&" +
            "client_secret=" + APP_SECRET_KEY + "&" +
            "code=" + code;

    URL url;
    String result = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(authURL);
        result = readURL(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] pairs;
    if (result != null) {
        pairs = result.split("&");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            String[] kv = pair.split("=");
            if (kv[0].equals("access_token")) {
                access_token = kv[1];
            }
        }
    }

    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId(APP_ID, APP_SECRET_KEY);
    AccessToken at = new AccessToken(access_token);
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(at);
    User currentUser = null;
    try {
        currentUser = facebook.users().getMe();
    } catch (FacebookException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return currentUser;
}
```

It works but it receives only userID and Name, all over fields are NULL. I need LastName, FirstName and Email.
What am i doing wrong? Please help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to read up on the Facebook API to figure out which call will give you first, last, and email.

Comment: Aren't there some "scopes" associated with the credentials you use to retrieve the access token?